# unable to convert string to integer in column data using the int function and readline function

Tags: python, string, integer

Reading the file using `readline` fuction
`f=open("meanstd","r")` *reading some file*

```
a=f.readlines()
b=[]
```

converting that column list data to integer form basically my data is in numerical form like **["0.7625" "0.8375"]** so I want to change this into integers form so that I can easily sum them without using any package.

```
for i in a: 
b.append(int(i))
print(b)
```

Comment: `0.7625` is not an integer. `int("0.7625")` raises a ValueError. Do you mean `float`?

Answer (score 1):

Your numbers are not int, they are float. So you can't append(int()). Luckily, Python has a float method that you can use.

Try this:

```
for i in a: 
b.append(float(i))
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be short answer for you;

**Code Syntax**

```
b = [float(val) for val in a]
print(b)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0.7625, 0.8375]
```